# Sorting Folders alphabetically using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to sort a large number of files folders from alphabetical blocks of four to each individual letter. I have been attempting to do this using a batch file but instead it appears to be copying every single file, no matter the first letter, to the folder for every single letter. I've tried a number of different methods and I have not found any success.

Here is the closest I have managed to get:

```
@echo off
@echo Started: %date% %time%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd "D:\The Files\A - D"
echo %time%: Processing Block A - D
for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
   echo %time%: Processing %%I
   xcopy "D:\The Files\A - D\%%I*" "D:\The Files\%%I" /E
)

@echo Finished: %date% %time%
```

I'm limited to using batch files by my network IT policy.

Comment: It should be `cd /D "D:\The Files\A - D"`, and based upon your location I presume therefore `for %%I In (A* B* C* D*) do…`. I would also advise that you use `echo !time!: Processing %%I` instead of `echo %time%: Processing %%I`. Gerhard has already shown you a method to capture each filename, and isolate the first character of each for the intended new directory locations.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to copy all the files based on the first character of the file. Considering the directories are actually `A - D` etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dest=D:\The Files"
for /D %%a in ("? - ?") do (
pushd "%%a"
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (
    set "line=%%~i"
    echo "%%a" xcopy "!line:~0,1!*%%~xi" "%dest%\!line:~0,1!" /E
 )
 popd
)
```

remove `echo` from the line before the closing parenthesis, only if the displayed results are what you are after to perform the actual copy.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
echo Started: %date% %time%
SET "dirs="A - D" "F - I" "J - M" "N - R" "S - V" "W - Z""
pushd "U:\The Files"
FOR %%s IN (%dirs%) DO (
 echo %time%: Processing Block %%~s
 for %%I in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
   IF EXIST ".\%%~s\%%I*" (
    echo %time%: Processing %%I
    ECHO xcopy "D:\The Files\%%~s\%%I*" "D:\The Files\%%I\" /E
   )
 )
)
popd

@echo Finished: %date% %TIME%
```

You've only given us one block, so I've guessed the rest. Also, I use `U:` for testing and the `xcopy` has been disarmed by an `echo` so that you can see what the `xcopy` command would be if the `echo` keyword was removed from the line.

`dirs` is set to a list of subdirectory-names. Each name is quoted and then the entire `set` command argument is quoted; hence it ends with two quotes.

Use `set "var1=value"` for setting **STRING** values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces.

Then, the `for %%s` takes each name in turn and applies it to `%%s` (including the quotes). We can then use `%%~s` to remove thos enclosing quotes.

So - for each letter, see whether any (presumed, file) exists in the current block that starts with the letter. If so, show the time & letter being processed and do the XCOPY.